# How configure ng serve in google vm to run with custom domain?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04

My vm running ubuntu 16.04 iso.
I modify /etc/hosts line:

127.0.0.1 localhost

to

127.0.0.1 mycustomdomain.com

and execute

ng serve --host mycustomdomain.com --port 8080 --environment prod